# Is "La razón de la quiebra fueron múltiples deudas" correct?

Tags: gramática, concordancia-verbal

No tengo claro si la concordancia es correcta en:

- *La razón de la quiebra fueron múltiples deudas.*

Creo que "La razón de la quiebra" sería el sujeto, "fueron" el núcleo oracional y "múltiples deudas" el atributo. Pero no sé si "múltiples deudas" se puede considerar como una sola razón, o ha de considerarse como varias, de forma que lo correcto sería:

- *Las razones de la quiebra fueron múltiples deudas.*

Comment: Las razones de la quiebra fueron múltiples deudas, mala gestión y problemas de caja. Sino razón al singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=4M7BtboGiD6n4FCqUu) dice que, cuando sujeto y predicativo subjetivo difieren en número, lo normal es establecer la concordancia en plural, a menos que el elemento que esté en plural pueda concebirse como una unidad (ver punto (c) más abajo):

> 2.1.1. Para establecer correctamente la concordancia del verbo ser en las oraciones copulativas, ha de tenerse en cuenta lo siguiente:
>
> a) Como norma general, ser debe concertar con el sujeto en número y persona: «Este club es una maravilla» (Bayly Días [Perú 1996]); «Algunas cosas son el colmo de la dificultad» (Cortázar Reunión [Arg. 1983]); «Vosotros sois gente que vive en Buenos Aires» (León Memoria [Esp. 1970]); «Ustedes son mi familia» (Espinosa Jesús [Méx. 1995]).
>
> b) No obstante, si el atributo es un pronombre personal, la concordancia, tanto de número como de persona, se establece necesariamente con este: «Dios somos nosotros» (Alviz Son [Esp. 1982]); «Mi diaria preocupación sois vosotros» (Maldonado Latifundios [Col. 1975]); «El culpable soy yo» (Darío Dama [Ven. 1989]).
>
> c) **Cuando el sujeto y el atributo son dos sustantivos que difieren en número, lo normal es establecer la concordancia con el elemento plural**: «Mi infancia son recuerdos de un patio de Sevilla» (Machado Campos [Esp. 1907-17] 491); «Todo eso son falacias» (Ott Dientes [Ven. 1999]); «La primera causa de regresión de la especie son las alteraciones de su hábitat» (DNavarra [Esp.] 20.5.99). **No obstante, en algunos casos es posible establecer la concordancia también en singular, en especial cuando uno de los dos sustantivos tiene significado colectivo, o cuando, siendo un plural morfológico, se refiere a un concepto unitario**: «Quienes desarrollaron la cultura de La Venta era gente de habla maya» (Ruz Mayas [Méx. 1981]); «El sueldo es tres mil dólares al mes» (Donoso Elefantes [Chile 1995]); «Las migas ruleras es un postre que se reserva para la cena» (Vergara Comer [Esp. 1981]).

Si queremos evitar la coexistencia de los dos números (singular y plural), podemos optar por parafrasear la oración:

- La razón de la quiebra fue la existencia de múltiples deudas.
- La quiebra se produjo por / a causa de / como resultado/consecuencia de múltiples deudas.

Comment: Gracias. Entonces en español casi siempre se escoge el plural. En inglés la concordancia es siempre con el sujeto ¿no? https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/verbs-sandwiched-between-singular-and-plural-nouns

Comment: @jinawee - Creo que lo que dijiste está bien.